# Suggestions for data modelling in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

I'm trying to figure out how to model this scenario in Neo4j.

I have a "product" node with a name attribute. The problem is that the name attribute can several variations across different languages which should all reference the same node.

I want to be able to search across the name and all of its variations to reference the one node.

.eg.

```
Name: Banana
Variation: Banano
Variation: Banane

etc.
```

Nodes:

```
Food {id: 1, name: "Banana"}
```

Translation {id: 1000, name: "Banane", language: "French"}

Relationship

```
(:Food)<-[:SIMILAR_TO]-(:translation)
```

I'm looking some more efficient that will easily work with an index for fast search.

Any suggestions on how to best model this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
(:Product {id: 1})-[:HAS_NAME]->(:Name {name:"Banana", lang:"en"})
         "        -[:HAS_NAME]->(:Name {name:"Banane", lang:"fr"})
         "        -[:HAS_NAME]->(:Name {name:"Banano", lang:"it"})

(:Product {id: 1})-[:SIMILAR_TO]->(:Food)
```

You can create a uniqueness constraint on `:Product id`, and an index on `:Name name`.

This way, you can easily find all the localized names for a specific product, and easily find all the products that have a specific name.